# In Xcode 6.1 I have two navigation buttons. But they are not visible on the Storyboard anymore. How do I get them back?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

So I have been working on an app for a bit now. Very New to iOS Development and have started straight in with Swift. I have several view controllers with navigation buttons. The buttons were placed by me on the storyboards but have have since disappears from the storyboards. Although when I run the app they are still appearing in the application and still function as coded.

I can see them in the side panel but I can't see them on the story boards. I have included some screen shots..

Can any explain why they are not on my storyboard any more and how I can get them back..

"https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGmxM.jpg"  - XCODE View

"https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPmFq.png"      - App View

Apologies for the links I can't post images on my first post...

Comment: screen shots please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your **top bar** simulated metric to **Inferred**

#### Top Bar: None

[image: Bar None]

#### Top Bar: Inferred

[image: Bar Inferred]

Assuming that your `UINavigationController` was added via *Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller*

Comment: Dude thank you so much. This totally fixed my problem. I have no idea how i turned this off in the first place haha.

Comment: Does **NOT** work in Xcode 6.4, seems to be a bug. Occasionally broken.